# Hide Bottom navigation bar in android 11?

Tags: android, android-11

I tried,

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        window.insetsController?.let {
          
            it.systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
          
            window.navigationBarColor = getColor(R.color.internal_black_semitransparent_light)

            it.hide(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars())
                                     }
}
```